# Efficient MySql Query

Tags: mysql

I want to design a query where I want to fetch a name from a second table based on the id from the first table. I am able to get the result using the following two queries.

Please, Let me know which one is efficient or gives fast result and why.

```
SELECT r1.id, c1.categoryName
FROM request r1 
LEFT JOIN category c1
ON r1.categoryId = c1.id
order by r1.dateCreated DESC;


SELECT id, (SELECT categoryName FROM category WHERE id 
= categoryId)
FROM request r1
order by dateCreated DESC;
```

Comment: You can used first query because of JOIN batter than Sub Query and you can visit the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query`

Comment: Better use first one. Subqueries increases server load as the number of records increases.

Comment: I will use joins instead of sub-query from now on. Thanks.

Comment: Sub query takes more time rather then the joins. So First one is good

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, explicit joins are the faster way to go, because the optimisation is better, but nowdays optimisers are getting better all the time, so you can try to go with a more readable SQL query.

You can find this in the manuals (13.2.10.11 Rewriting Subqueries as Joins): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

It says "A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better".

But in complex cases I prefer subquery, they have more readability, and your SQL will be more maintainable, Sub-queries are the logically correct way to solve problems.